# Is there a way to minimize computer usage except for one program?

Tags: windows-7, cpu, sleep

I have a large desktop that I want to run one script repeatedly, and that one script shouldn't be too cpu intensive. I literally don't plan on using the computer for anything except running the one script.

Is there a way to basically put to sleep everything except the bare minimums to run the program?  I'm trying to conserve electricity.

I'm on Windows 7.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Windows is quite complicated, and has *numerous* maintenance processes. If the intended use is just one application, and if it runs well in another OS, e.g. [Windows RE (WinRE)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-recovery-environment--windows-re--technical-reference), or [Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.me/) under [wine](https://wine.htmlvalidator.com/install-wine-on-lubuntu-20.04.html), you may find the PC uses less energy with the alternative OS than under a full Windows version.

Since either [WinRE](https://www.idrive.com/disk-image-winre-bootable-media) or [Lubuntu](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/put-lubuntu-on-a-flash-drive-using-windows/) can be run from USB without needing any installation to HDD or SDD, you could test these alternatives on your specific PC, comparing their power usage, and that from Windows 7, with a [watt meter](https://www.amazon.com/watt-meter/s?k=watt%20meter).

However, the PC architecture may be the biggest obstacle to efficiency. Many newer PC's use far less power than older ones. so why not move to a dedicated device such as the [Raspeberry Pi 3B](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-3-model-b/), which about [1.3 watts idling, and about 2 watts full bore](https://raspi.tv/2019/how-much-power-does-the-pi4b-use-power-measurements)?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to reduce the Windows setup to the minimum, you may open
*Control Panel > Programs and Features > Turn Windows features on or
off*
and disable the features you don't need. However, you won't gain
much performance from it, because most of these features do not use
any resources unless the program is invoked.

If you still want to give your process higher priority,
you may start it using:

```
start /<priority> <command>
```

where "priority" is any of:
LOW, NORMAL, HIGH, REALTIME, ABOVENORMAL, BELOWNORMAL.

I suggest using HIGH or ABOVENORMAL, but never REALTIME, as your script
will then compete with essential Windows processes on equal basis,
so performance will rather degrade.

You may also increase the priority of a running process, by starting
Task Manager, right-click on the process, and select "Set Priority*.